# Itext generated PDF document to S3 server

Tags: java, spring, pdf, amazon-s3

I am trying to setup a website where you can "finish order" and then the order is generated in PDF-format. Then I need the pdf-file to be uploaded directly to my S3-bucket

I am fairly new to this so I don't know where to start.

Right now I have made some test code where I make a PDF file with "test" in it.

I have already made an image uploader with my S3-bucket, so I am familiar with how that works.

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("PATH");
document.open();
document.add(new Paragraph("Test");
document.close();
```

What I want to know is: How do I take this document object and parse it to an S3 server? I have searched everywhere and can't find anything.

Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented for me. `content` is `byte[]` of uploading file

```
final ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setSSEAlgorithm(ObjectMetadata.AES_256_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION);
metadata.setContentType(contentType);
metadata.setContentLength(content.length);
final String md5Hex = DigestUtils.md5Hex(new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(content)));
final PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest("bucketName", "folderName" + "/" + md5Hex,
        new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(content)), metadata);

final PutObjectResult s3Result = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient().putObject(putObjectRequest);
```